# Querying domain field from /etc/resolv.conf using Linux API (resolv.h)

Tags: linux, domain-name

I'm trying to extract **domain** entry from */etc/resolv.conf*.

For instance, from the following file, I want to get *my.domain.com* using standard Linux API, but I couldn't find any corresponding entries from *struct __res_state* defined from */usr/include/resolv.h*.

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN   
nameserver 127.0.1.1 
domain my.domain.com 
search localdomain
```

Easy way is to parse the file and extract any string literal that follows domain keyword, but I expect to find a somewhat standard way to get it.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!